# Invoke function once, only after JQuery created images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been searching for a solution but all i'm getting is $(window).on("load", fuction(){}) which just loads the html resources. 
I'm creating a variable amount of images and inserting them in a div with jquery using an each() function after the window is loaded.

```
$.each(footeradds, function(fad){
    $("<div class=\"footerads\"><img src=\"image" + fad + ".jpg\"/></div>").appendTo(".footer");
});
```

I need to calculate the width of the container of these images which depends on the amount of images and their width, which they only have after they've loaded.

if i do

```
$(".footer img").on("load", function() {})
```

that function is called every time an image loads, and need it to only be called once, after ALL images have loaded.

My question is: how can i invoke a function after images created with jquery are loaded?

Comment: `$(".footer img").one("load", function() {})`

Comment: @Rayon this will be called for the first loaded image, OP wants to execute callback once all images will be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no methods for it but you can do one thing

take a variable `A` = count all images  , then create other variable `B` = 1 and increment it on every image load and
check condition `A == B`

that condition will true when last image will called .....:)

Answer (score 0):

Turn the event off after first time

```
$(".footer img").on("load", function() {
    $( this ).off( event );
})
```

Comment: this way it'll get invoked when the first image is loaded. what about the others? i need all of them to be loaded before the function happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a deferred for each image, and `$.when` to check that all are resolved etc

```
var p = $.map(footeradds, function(fad){

    var def = new $.Deferred,
        div = $('<div />', {
            'class' : 'footerads'
        }),
        img = $('<img />', {
            on  : {
                load : function() {
                  def.resolve(this);
              }
            },
            src : 'image' + fad + '.jpg'
        });

    $(".footer").append( div.append(img) );

    return def.promise();
});

$.when.apply($, p).then(function(images) {
    // all images loaded
    var images = [].slice.call(arguments);
    // use images here
});
```

Comment: Generally `src` is being set after `load` handler(May be to avoid _cached- image_ scenario), Is it also applicable with `jQuery( html, attributes )` ?

Comment: with this i can't use a global array for some reason

Comment: @Rayon - not sure if it's important in jQuery, but doesn't hurt to swap them.

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept - what exactly does "global array" mean ?

Comment: @adeneo i mean that the array was created in a way that i should be able to use it in this function. it was created before everything else. like when variables are global.

Comment: @SuzanneEdelmanCreoconcept - I'm not sure what you mean, but if you wanted the images in the `$.when` handler, you'd just pass them. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So i ended up using Pratik Bhalodiya's idea and made this:

```
var footerW = 0;
var fimgs = 0;
$(".footer img").on('load', function() {
    footerW += + $(this).width();
    fimgs++;
    if (fimgs == $(".footerads").length){
        //do stuff here
    }
});
```

thanks for your help everyone!